# using select in case statement sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

If I have a table called Table - Food_Preferences as seen below

```
NAME   FOOD     COUNTRY  
Jim    Rice     US  
Jim    Salad    US  
Jim    Dessert  US  
Kim    Rice     JAP  
Kim    Salad    JAP  
Tim    Rice     UK  
Tim    Dessert  UK
```

I want a query which gives result as below (Show Rice only if country is JAP else show other Foods)

```
Jim  Salad   US  
Jim  Dessert US  
Kim  Rice    JAP  
Kim  Salad   JAP  
Tim  Dessert UK
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask], and [edit] your question to include your current attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select
    *
from 
    myTable
where
    1 = case 
            when FOOD = 'Rice' and COUNTRY <> 'JAP' then 0
            else 1
    end
```

Comment: no need to for a case expression here.... A simple `WHERE FOOD <> 'Rice' OR COUNTRY = 'JAP'` will do the same.

Comment: Yeah. You are right. But I think it is more easier to understand with `CASE` statement. At least for me :)